# What is the most efficient method to compute this matrix?

Tags: python, matrix

I have a N-square matrix B of integers and i want to build the matrix A such that

```
A[m,n] = sum([B[i,j] for i in range(1,m) for j in range(1,n)])
```

As B can be quite big, computing A naively coefficient by coefficient takes much time.
What is the most effective way to compute A ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

A = np.cumsum(np.cumsum(a, axis=0), axis=1)
```

You're in luck. Two calls to numpy.cumsum (cumulative sum) should do the trick.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html

Comment: No problem. If it solves your question it might be worth marking it as answered.